# UNITY: How to get the coordinates of the SafeArea rect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, safeareaview

I am working on a project in Unity for Android Portrait mode. I will constantly be modifying the textures of two RawImages, the catch is that the images must be the same width and height(1080x1080, 800x800) 1080x1079 is wrong. Because a lot of phones nowadays are notched, I'm forced to maintain all the UI Elements inside the SafeArea rect. BUT, I don't know how to get the y coordinate of the SafeArea rect relative to the Display. Here's a photo:
[image: Here's a photo]

So, I only need to get the y coordinate of the SafeArea rect, by my guesses, for the Phone in the example, the y coordinate should be around 100 pixels height. Thank you in advance.

Comment: hey, please check this article this might help you, [Updating your GUI for the iPhone X and other “Notched” Devices](https://connect.unity.com/p/updating-your-gui-for-the-iphone-x-and-other-notched-devices)

Comment: Hey, you can use Screen.safeArea that returns the safe area of the screen in pixels.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-safeArea.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **UI Scale Mode:** *Scale with screen size* [Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAnIG.png), here is my solution for adaptive RectTransform with your safe area (only Vertical):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class MySafeArea : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private CanvasScaler canvasScaler;
        private float bottomUnits, topUnits;
        void Start()
        {
            canvasScaler = FindObjectOfType<CanvasScaler>();
            ApplyVerticalSafeArea();
        }
    
        
        public void ApplyVerticalSafeArea()
        {
            var bottomPixels = Screen.safeArea.y;
            var topPixel = Screen.currentResolution.height - (Screen.safeArea.y + Screen.safeArea.height);
    
            var bottomRatio = bottomPixels / Screen.currentResolution.height;
            var topRatio = topPixel / Screen.currentResolution.height;
    
            var referenceResolution = canvasScaler.referenceResolution;
            bottomUnits = referenceResolution.y * bottomRatio;
            topUnits = referenceResolution.y * topRatio;
    
            var rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(rectTransform.offsetMin.x, bottomUnits);
            rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(rectTransform.offsetMax.x, -topUnits);
        }
    }
```

Just attach this script to your RectTransform with [stretched anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3l9X.png) and [enjoy the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpS1q.png)